# Update non active linux installation

Tags: centos, upgrade, live-usb

We have several linux (Centos) live usb drives and I was wondering whether it was possible to just mount and update them from a linux desktop (running from a HDD) instead of booting and running yum on each one.

Comment: A `chroot` into the mount point might do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have mounted them somewhere (/media/usb) do a `chroot /media/usb /bin/bash` to chroot into the USB system. Do whatever you need to do and `exit` afterwards. Replace `/bin/bash` if you prefer another shell or bash isn't available.